# How to escape a double quote in JSON column using java?

Tags: java, json, gson

For example I'm getting a message from host with this column:

```
\"ID\":\"\"test" 001\"
```

unescaped:

```
"ID":""test" 001"
```

JSON parser is throwing an exception due to double quotes. How could I find columns that have double quotes and remove them in Java?

Comment: escape the double quotes after test

Comment: The JOSN file has over 50 columns, so I was wondering if I could have a generic way of inspecting all column for double quotes and escape them. Could you please give me an example snippet?

Comment: Might want to study up on regex.

Answer (score 0):

before sending the JSON string do something like

```
jsonString.replace('"', '\\\"')
```

Comment: This will not work. `'\"'` is equivalent to `'"'`. Assuming a String can be entered as the second parameter, he would have to do: `jsonString.replace('"', "\\\"")`